# iPhone app and backend communication

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, json, networking

I am sending data back and forth between my java webserver and iOS app. When I send single requests, it works fine. However, when I send 10 requests from the iPhone(one for each cell in my UITableView which needs unique information), the request does not work properly. Let me explain what is going on:

My iOS app is creating an NSData object with the data returned from the server. I am using the `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData]` method to turn this into a NSDictionary. I am receiving an error stating there is garbage data at the end. When I inspect the buffer, I see my first JSON string come in, but has the next JSON string appended to it as well.

How do I tackle the problem of my server sending back the requests in one string(since it processes it so fast).

I am using Apple's NSStream class to handle communication.

A bit of the code in -

```
 `(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent:`



case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        {
            //can read input
            if (theStream == inputStream) {
                if (inputStream.hasBytesAvailable) {
                    uint8_t buf[4096];
                    unsigned int len = 0;
                    len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:4096];
                        if(len > 0 && len < 4096) {
                            NSError *error;
                            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:len] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                            if (error) {
```

When I examine the error it says garbage at end. I receive an error when the request looks like this:

```
{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abbott, Philip C","overall":2,"reviews":21}]}{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abel, Gavin Paul","overall":0,"reviews":0}]}{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abel, Steven Richard","overall":5,"reviews":1}]}{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abney, Scott A","overall":0,"reviews":0}]}{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abraham, Dulcy M","overall":0,"reviews":0}]}{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abraham, John ","overall":0,"reviews":0}]}{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abramova, Inna ","overall":0,"reviews":0}]}{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abu-Omar, Mahdi M","overall":0,"reviews":0}]}{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Acharya, Lalatendu ","overall":0,"reviews":0}]}{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Acosta, Glen G","overall":0,"reviews":0}]}
```

as opposed to single requests like this:

```
 {"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abbott, Philip C","overall":2,"reviews":21}]}


{"command":"PROFESSOR_RATING","error":false,"data":[{"professor":"Abel, Gavin Paul","overall":0,"reviews":0}]}
```

..and so forth

How do I split this up into each JSON string? What are my options? Do I need to change the way my server sends the data?

Server:

```
String request = commands[1];
String results = submitReview(request);                     
bw.write(results);
bw.flush();
```

I have tried manually parsing through it, but run into problems when I have a full request(a valid JSON string), appended by a LONG Json String(which is not valid because it does not fit into the buffer, and the rest will be sent in the next inputStream event)). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks so much.

-Kamran

Comment: How do you download the data ? Did you tried using a library like AFNetworking ?

Comment: I just edited the post because I accidentally left this out. I am using NSStream to communicate with my server.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar need for my app, and we use the [AFNetworking stuff](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).  It lets me have multiple streams pulling separate data chunks, and is really awesome.  I know our Android app can't even come to close to us in performance due to our multithreading.

You can queue up a number of requests, then have a queue manager pull them off on as many threads as you want to have going at once, and have success and failure blocks.

we set stuff up like this:

```
  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id array) {
        [processingQueue_ addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self.syncDelegate saveBigs:array];
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                [self finished:title];
            }];
        }];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self failed:title error:error retrySelector:@selector(getBigs) withObject:nil errorCode:operation.response.statusCode type:NETWORK_OPERATION_TYPE_BIG];
    }];

     [queue_ addOperation:operation];
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the problem lies with how I am handling networking on the front end, but how my server keeps sending data out. I think the technique used aggregate the data is not as relevant as the way the data is dispersed.

Comment: I still think you would have less grief if you went to AFNetworking.